# JSON change value of the key with loop

Tags: javascript, json, loops, for-loop

I would like to loop through JSON keys and if the key has empty string as a value replace this empty string with the name of key. I can get the name of key but when I get his value that is undefined.

JSON:

```
"Forget": "",
"Login": "Login2"
```

JS:

```
...
var jsonKeys = Object.keys(json),
jsonKeysLength = jsonKeys.length;

for(var i=0; i < jsonKeysLength; i++){
   var key,
       translateValue = jsonKeys[i][key];
   if( translateValue == "" ) {
      translateValue = jsonKeys[i];
   }
}
return json;
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `for ... in` loop construct.

```
for (let keyName in json) {
    let value = json[keyName]
    if (value === '') {
        json[keyName] = keyName
    }
}
```

The `for ... in` loop will automatically iterate over all **iterable** properties in the object and bind it to the `keyName` variable.